# Как подключить шрифт

Tags: html5

Я хочу использовать на сайте Bookman Old Style. Как мне осуществить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'MyUnderwoodRegular';
 src: url('MyUnderwood-webfont.eot');
 src: local('☺'), url('MyUnderwood-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('MyUnderwood-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }
```

После этого можно использовать шрифт MyUnderwoodRegular

Например так:

```
 p {
 font: 60px/68px 'MyUnderwoodRegular', Arial, sans-serif
 }
```